# opening intent for showing image and video in Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I want to opening an intent when i click on an thumbnail of an image or video . Below is the code works for mw sucessfully :

```
void startIntentForShowingOutgoingFile(String fileName,String filePath){

    File file = null;
    Intent i = new Intent();
    if (fileName.contains(".jpg") || fileName.contains(".jpeg")
            || fileName.contains(".png") || fileName.contains(".gif")
            || fileName.contains(".bmp")) {
        file = new File(filePath);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
    } else if (fileName.contains(".amr") || fileName.contains(".mp3")
            || fileName.contains(".wav") || fileName.contains(".mid")) {
        file = new File(filePath);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
    } else if (fileName.contains(".mpeg") || fileName.contains(".3gp")) {
        file = new File(filePath);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
    } else if (fileName.contains(".txt") || fileName.contains(".csv")
            || fileName.contains(".xml")) {
        file = new File(filePath);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
    }

    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (file != null) {

        startActivity(i);
    }
```

this code opens image or video in a full screen . but i want to open image and video like in a small window. How can i achieve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to create dynamic [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html).